# How to add field into search widget in adempiere

Tags: search, adempiere

I want to add new field into search widget in adempiere. As an example my search widget already have name and description fields. In addition to that I want to add address_id field. I do not know how to do this. If anybody know how to do this? Please help me..

Answer (score 3):

Let me see if I got you right.

You have a table, and when you hit the search button, the search window display **"name"** and **"description"** fields.

You want to add **"address_id"** as an additional search criteria.

As System Administrator, you need to go to **"Table & Column"**, search for your table and then go to the **"Column"** tab and search the column **"address_id"**. There you need to check the **"Selection Column"** mark.

HIH

Answer (score 0):

Create column address_id in Your table and make Selection Column (check box) true.